# Javamail A5 Bad Command

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have a mail account in server of Brazil host (uol.com.br). This account for tests, have 7.000 messages in inbox. When I connect by java mail and setDebug(true), the messages doesn't returning and show this message:

```
03-22 14:44:07.305: I/System.out(5524): A1 OK User logged in
03-22 14:44:07.320: I/System.out(5524): A2 CAPABILITY
03-22 14:44:07.435: I/System.out(5524): * CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 QUOTA UIDPLUS NO_ATOMIC_RENAME UNSELECT CHILDREN MULTIAPPEND BINARY SORT
03-22 14:44:07.435: I/System.out(5524): A2 OK Completed
03-22 14:44:07.500: I/System.out(5524): A3 LIST "" "%"
03-22 14:44:07.835: I/System.out(5524): * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "." "INBOX"
03-22 14:44:07.850: I/System.out(5524): * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "." "Quarentena"
03-22 14:44:07.870: I/System.out(5524): * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "." "Drafts"
03-22 14:44:07.885: I/System.out(5524): * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "." "Sent Messages"
03-22 14:44:07.925: I/System.out(5524): * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "." "Deleted Messages"
03-22 14:44:07.950: I/System.out(5524): A3 OK Completed (0.000 secs 6 calls)
03-22 14:44:07.990: I/System.out(5524): DEBUG: connection available -- size: 1
03-22 14:44:07.995: I/System.out(5524): A4 SELECT INBOX
03-22 14:44:08.130: I/System.out(5524): * FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen)
03-22 14:44:08.145: I/System.out(5524): * OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen \*)]  
03-22 14:44:08.160: I/System.out(5524): * 7245 EXISTS
03-22 14:44:08.170: I/System.out(5524): * 1 RECENT
03-22 14:44:08.180: I/System.out(5524): * OK [UNSEEN 7243]  
03-22 14:44:08.190: I/System.out(5524): * OK [UIDVALIDITY 1208433603]  
03-22 14:44:08.235: I/System.out(5524): * OK [UIDNEXT 10125]  
03-22 14:44:08.235: I/System.out(5524): A4 OK [READ-WRITE] Completed
03-22 14:44:21.555: I/System.out(5524): A5 SEARCH UNSEEN ALL
03-22 14:44:23.910: I/System.out(5524): A5 BAD Unsupported command.
```

This is part of code to set an flag. In gmail this code is fine for 100 messages in inbox folder

```
public Message[] getInboxMessages() {
        Message[] messages = null;
        try {

            Flags f1 = new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN);
            FlagTerm notseen = new FlagTerm(f1, false);

            messages = mInboxFolder.search(notseen);            

        } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, e.getMessage());

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        return messages;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your code please?

Comment: Todd i was edited the question with part of code. This same code work perfectly in Gmail accounts with 100 messages in inbox.

Comment: A5 isn't the command, it's basically a request identifier for the IMAP protocol.  Perhaps the server you're connecting to does not support the SEARCH UNSEEN ALL command.

Comment: Hi @Mateus. Did you get any response from your Server (UOL)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server is broken.  It doesn't appear to be supporting the IMAP protocol properly.  Report the bug to the server vendor.

If you need to work around the server bug, you'll need to avoid using that "search" command.  You can get all the messages and just skip the ones that are marked SEEN.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error when using [smtp4dev](https://github.com/rnwood/smtp4dev). I opened [an issue there](https://github.com/rnwood/smtp4dev/issues/1244) and will update this answer if I find a solution.